# Save a query result on a variable

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

I´m trying to save a SQLAlchemy query result on a python variable (in case there is one result) in order to insert it with other data later. Is there any chance to do something like that?

Things you may want to know:

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle DB
I'm using python 3.7.1

Till now I´ve been able to do this:**

```
try:
                        
    map_projn_id_search = Session.execute("""
    SELECT GEOFRAME_MAP_PROJN_ID 
    FROM V_GEOFRAME_MAP_PROJN 
    WHERE COORD_REF_SYS_CODE = :crs AND TRNSFRM = :tfm"""
    , {"crs" : crs , "tfm" : tfm} )

    map_projn_id_search.fetchone()
                        
except Exception as e:
    print("error")
                        
else:
    #If it doesn´t exist I need to insert it into the V_GEOFRAME_MAP_PROJN 
    if map_projn_id_search.rowcount == 0:
            
        instances_with_unkown = ['SAMSDB', 'CASSDB', 'CCUSDB', 'EMASDB', 'EMLSDB', 'HNOSDB', 'KULSDB', 'NAFSDB', 'RUSSDB', 'YUZSDB', 'AMESDB', 'LAGSDB']
        instances_with_UNKNWON =[ 'USASDB']

        if emsdb_instance in instances_with_unkown:
                
            projn_id = "Unknown"

            print(f'\n The EPSG code (ProjCRS:GeogCRS:Tfm) does not exist on EMSDB. Set {projn_id} as CRS. \n')
                  
            
        elif emsdb_instance in instances_with_UNKNWON:
                
            projn_id = "UNKNOWN"

            print(f'\n The EPSG code (ProjCRS:GeogCRS:Tfm) does not exist on EMSDB. Set {projn_id} as CRS. \n')
                

        else:
            #If it exists then print that it exists so the user knows
            print("\n Cannot insert the EPSG code (ProjCRS:GeogCRS:Tfm) on that database. \n")
                
                                                   
    elif map_projn_id_search.rowcount != 0:
        #If it exists then print that it exists so the user knows

        projn_id = map_projn_id_search.fetchone()

        print(f"\n Set {projn_id} as the CRS of the survey. \n")
```

Answer (score 0):

So, what I needed to do is:

Add a variable like

a = map_projn_id_search.fetchone()

And then make another who could fetch the first result as a string instead of a list

b = a[0]